# Unpack interaction terms from formula in R

Tags: r

I'm working on creating a function in R that can expand interaction terms from a given formula string. The goal is to break down the formula string to represent all individual variables and their interactions.

For instance, if the function is given the string `'A*B'`, it should return the character vector `c('A', 'B', 'A:B')`.

Similarly, for the input `'A:B*C'`, the expected output should be `c('A:B', 'C', 'A:B:C')`.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to best approach this or if there's any existing function/package that can assist with this task. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: `step_interact` from the `recipes` package creates the interaction terms between variables. Looking at the resulting output in the [documented examples](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_interact.html#ref-examples), are the `names(df)` essentially what you want?

Comment: @Seth not really the ouctome I am looking for: `library(tidymodels); library(magrittr); recipe(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris) %>% step_interact(terms = ~ Sepal.Width:Petal.Length*Petal.Width) %>% prep(training = iris) %>% bake(iris) %>% names()` returns `c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width_x_Petal.Length", "Sepal.Width_x_Petal.Length_x_Petal.Width")`. The expected outcome is: `c("Sepal.Width:Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Width:Petal.Length:Petal.Width")`

Comment: Can you please add the code-containing comment to your question through EDIT? Readability, reproducibility and consistency is much better with a complete question since not everyone sieves through the comments to stitch together all requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn input into a formula using `reformulate` and then use `terms`/`labels` as shown.  No packages are used.

```
unpack <- function(x) labels(terms(reformulate(x)))

unpack("A*B")
## [1] "A"   "B"   "A:B"

unpack("A:B*C")
## [1] "C"     "A:B"   "A:B:C"

unpack(c("A*B", "A:B*C"))
## [1] "A"     "B"     "C"     "A:B"   "A:B:C"

unpack(c("A*B + A:B*C")) # same
## [1] "A"     "B"     "C"     "A:B"   "A:B:C"
```

### Update

Have replaced `formula(paste("~", x))` with `reformulate(x)` as per
Ben Bolker comment.